# Upstart: unrecognized service (CentOS 6.4)

Tags: centos, java, upstart

I have created an upstart service from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/leon/2204773). I put it into:

```
[andrey@vm01 ~]$ ll /etc/init/play.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1255 Dec  1 20:50 /etc/init/play.conf
```

I also installed upstart, as it was missing on my system:

```
sudo yum install upstart
```

I restarted several times, but I'm still getting this error:

```
[andrey@vm01 ~]$ sudo service play status
[sudo] password for andrey:
play: unrecognized service
```

Do you have any ideas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know the reason for this, but the problem was with the name of the command line tool which in my distribution is 'initctl'. The following version works fine:

```
sudo initctl status play
```

Comment: The problem was not solved... on RHEL 6.5